# Laravel 5.4 - Route does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have a simple link on a page to a URL test:

```
<a href="{{ URL('test')}}" title="test">
```

In web.php I have defined:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    $parts = DB::table('partdetails')->limit(100);
    dd($parts);
    return view('test',compact($parts));
    })->name('test');
```

I also have a very basic view in the root directory of resources\views call test.blade.php.

When I try this I get

> The requested resource /test was not found on this server.

I cannot get this!

Comment: do your other routes works normally?

Comment: yes - just this one!

Comment: do you have a folder under `test` name in your public directory?

Comment: Out at the moment but I will check. I don't think so. Can't understand why DD do not kick in first

Comment: There is no subdirectory test

Comment: remove the code :     dd($parts);

Comment: tried that, no joy but see comments below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things come to mind..

1. If you have a wildcard route, move it to the bottom of your routes file.
2. Make sure your `.htaccess` file is like the one coming with Laravel.
3. Make sure `APP_URL` in **.env** is correct
4. If you have Laravel installed in a sub-folder, you should search how to setup that correctly. There are tons of info on the web, easy to find.

Comment: If I change the name from test to testpage it all works fine.....Weird.....

Comment: Saeed thanks for your comments. All of them are correct. I wonder why test is not OK!

Comment: Is it local or on a web server, perhaps shared web server? If you haven't added this behavior, it could be some global configuration on the web server.

Comment: Saeed it is local.

Comment: Hmm, you need to do some more debugging then to find the issue. I suggest you create a new Laravel app, an empty one, simply add the test route and see if that works. If it has the same issue, then it must be some server level configuration that is causing it. However if it does work, then the error must be on site level, perhaps you've added some package? Also try `php artisan route:list` and see if you find anything weird on the test route..

Comment: Thanks. This is a route on other packages without problems so I suppose some package is screwing it up.